# CMD+Tab (app switcher) for switching between open programs is not working on mac anymore?

Tags: mac

My shortcut CMD+Tab for switching between open windows/programs is not working since yesterday, it is opening the panel with all open programs, but when I try to change program it is witching back to the first one(the far left one)in the panel all the time?

This is also happening in my Launchpad, when I try to swipe to the next group of programs it switches back to the first group?

I have tried to kill the Dock in the Activity Control, I have also tried to delete the dock completely and restarted the computer but no luck, so what can be the problem?

I use this all the time so I need it to work, so any help really appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: First steps… Test in Safe Mode, test on a different admin account. Report back.

Comment: Thanks. How do I use Safe Mode? I only have one user account.

Comment: Safe Mode = Shift key at boot chimes. You'll have to make a 2nd account to test.

Comment: ok I will test it.

Comment: Ok I created a new admin account and logged in there but it was the same problem!?

Comment: & what happened in Safe Mode?

Comment: I don't know if anything happened? What do you think about should happened? I just logged in to the other account and opened safari to test it between the finder and safari and it still jumped back to the fist one.

Comment: I'm not following you… there are two tests. Test 1. Boot into Safe mode & see if it still behaves incorrectly. Test 2. Login to a different account & see if it still behaves incorrectly. We could add a test 3. Try a different keyboard.

Comment: If I understand it right, the problem relates to the Dock? But I have already tried that? What else can I do?

Comment: Ok, sorry I will test to boot into safe mode, I thought I did, but how do I know that Im in Safe mode? Will be back in 15 min.

Comment: Ok will boot in safe mode now.

Comment: Ok I tried to start in Safe mode, I hold down the shift key until the login screen appered and then I loged in. But when I check what mode Im in, it still says normal when I look at "About this mac", "System Report", "Software". So I don´t know why I can´t start in Safe mode!?

Comment: OK so now Im in safe mode but the problem is the same. I hope I can test with another keyboard later, I will see if I can borrow one to test with. Anything else I can try with? Thanks.

Comment: Finally! I shut down the computer with the button on the back, not just restarting it, and now it works again!! I have no idea why but thanks for your help before Tetsujin